# Differences between refinery and ::refinery

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ROR and Refinery. So I'm stuck in understanding the syntax. Can you please tell me the difference between:

```
class X < Refinery::AdminController
```

and

```
class X < ::Refinery::AdminController
```

Answer (score 4):

In the event that your class is defined inside a module (namespacing, for example), the `::` at the beginning of the class definition tells Rails to look for the module at the base (without the namespacing).  As a more concrete example, if you have a class defined as follows:

```
module Foo
  class MyController < Refinery::AdminController
  end
end
```

Rails will try to find `Refinery::AdminController` within the Foo module. If, however, you define your class in this format:

```
module Foo
  class MyController < ::Refinery::AdminController
  end
end
```

Rails will only look for `Refinery::AdminController` only at the base level and not within `Foo`.